# Rachmaninoff - Piano Concerto No. 2 (1st movement): How to play tremolo together with a 3-note chord? at Bar 313-314, Bar 319-320

Tags: piano, chords, tremolo-system, tremolo, romantic-period

Looking into the [Rachmaninoff - Piano Concerto No. 2 (1st movement) solo piano (arranged by LotusFlower](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v5eFcwzr7mDyyGqgTcH8d40_HDxIapFJ/view), see the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qh0EO_YbKWU),
there are those 3 horizontal bars known as **Tremolo** at 7:00 and at 9:23. It means alternating pitches like a trill, except a trill is always a step up and a tremolo can be any interval in either direction.

The 3 horizontal bars mean 32nd (1/32) note speed for tremolo.

**My question--** how to play those tremolos correctly,

for those happen at

- Bar 313-314 with a 3-note chord for the half note (how to play tremolo together with a chord?).
- Bar 319-320 with a 3-note chord for the half note  (how to play tremolo together with a chord??).

At 7:00

[image]

At 9:23

[image]

Comment: It's not clear how the first video (the @7:00 one) and score excerpt relate to your question.

Answer (score 1):

**mm. 313 – 314:** The tremolo is just the G octave. The upper part of the chord is played with the right hand. The right hand just happens to be written in the left-hand staff for ease of reading, but the technique is the same as in measures 315 – 316, where it's perhaps more obvious.

**mm. 317 – 320:** The tremolo is just the upper notes. However, one needs Rachmaninoff-sized hands to pay it as written. For hands with a smaller-than-Rach span, one plays the lower tied notes first (the F in mm. 317 – 318, the G and D in mm. 319 – 320), then tremolo on the upper pair of notes.

The pianist in the video actually demonstrates this very well. Try watching at half-speed (or slower).